# Delete multiple tables SQL

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I have tried to delete multiple data/rows tables, but does not allow me as the error starts at -> a, b, c, d, e <- that says "invalid column" and not find what is my mistake ... here my code:

```
DELETE a.*,b.*,c.*,d.*,e.* FROM [CatMngSys].[Providers] a
INNER JOIN [Security].[UsersProviders] b
ON a.Id = b.ProviderId
INNER JOIN [Security].[Users] c
ON b.UserId = c.Id
INNER JOIN [CatMngSys].[ProviderSubscriptions] d
ON d.ProviderId = a.Id
INNER JOIN [CatMngSys].[Subscriptions] e
ON e.Id = d.SubscriptionId
WHERE a.id = @Id
```

and i have tried for many options:

```
DELETE FROM 
DELETE * FROM
DELETE a.*,b.*,c.*,d.*,e.*
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

```
 DROP TABLE table1,table2,table3 ...
```

Comment: hmmm i don't want to delete the tables... only specific rows of every tables

Comment: joining a-b-c-d, tryed this? WHERE a.id=b.providerId AND b.userid=c.id ..... instead of a.id=@id.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE t1, t2 
FROM t1 
INNER JOIN t2 
INNER JOIN t3
WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND t2.id = t3.id;
```

Comment: ... sorry i need to delete multiple tables, not one table

Answer (score 0):

Remove the columns (*) from the DELETE clause:

```
DELETE a, b, c, d, e
FROM [CatMngSys].[Providers] a
INNER JOIN [Security].[UsersProviders] b ON a.Id = b.ProviderId
INNER JOIN [Security].[Users] c ON b.UserId = c.Id
INNER JOIN [CatMngSys].[ProviderSubscriptions] d ON d.ProviderId = a.Id
INNER JOIN [CatMngSys].[Subscriptions] e ON e.Id = d.SubscriptionId
WHERE a.id = @Id
```

This'll delete matching rows in each of tables `Providers`, `UsersProviders`, `Users`, `ProviderSubscriptions` and `Subscriptions`.

Comment: Is it SQL Server? What error or incorrect response are you seeing. Can you create two test tables with data and test the same type of query?